# How can I simulate hoverIntent on this block of code?

Tags: jquery, mouseenter, mouseleave, hoverintent

I have asked the same in a [previous topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098410/mouseenter-adds-overflownone-how-can-i-prevent-this-and-how-can-i-simulate) but someone said that I should open another for this. So here it goes:

I'm animating a ribbon behind the navigation and the problem is that I want to keep the animated element in the previous place instead of going back to the starting position and coming back to the next element. I was able to achieve this, but without the use of hoverIntent. So now the ribbon will pick up every single movement on the navigation. How can I prevent this?

Correct me if I'm wrong but delay() and setTimeout() did not make sense at this point since they would fire up the last animation regardless of the stops. How can I prevent the mouseenter from firing up if the mouse is just passing by? Maybe an if clause on mouseover like if mouse is stable on the hovering block for more than 300 ms?

*Note: I'm running a noConflict script, hence j = $.*

```
function rbHover(){


    j("#nav li a")
        .on('mouseenter', function() {

        var l = j(this).parent().position().left;
        var w = j(this).parent().width();
        var rbw = Math.round(w/4);
        var rbh = Math.round(w/16);

            j("#ribbon").stop('ribbon', true, true).animate({
                "left" : l,
                "width" : w }, {
                    duration: 600,
                    easing: 'swing', 
                    queue: 'ribbon'
                 }).dequeue('ribbon');

            j(".rib-left").stop('rib-left', true, true).animate({
                "border-right-width": rbw,
                "border-left-width": rbw,
                "border-top-width": rbh,
                "border-bottom-width": rbh,
                "bottom": "-" + (2*rbh) + "px"}, {
                    duration:600,
                    easing: 'linear', 
                    queue: 'rib-left'
                 }).dequeue('rib-left');

            j(".rib-right").stop('rib-right', true, true).animate({
                "border-right-width": rbw,
                "border-left-width": rbw,
                "border-top-width": rbh,
                "border-bottom-width": rbh,
                "bottom": "-" + (2*rbh) + "px"}, {
                    duration:600,
                    easing: 'linear', 
                    queue: 'rib-right'
                 }).dequeue('rib-right');
        })

        .on('mouseleave', function() {

        var l = j(".active").parent().position().left;
        var w = j(".active").parent().width();
        var rbw = Math.round(w/4);
        var rbh = Math.round(w/16);

            j("#ribbon").stop('ribbon', true).delay(300, 'ribbon').animate({
                "left" : l,
                "width" : w }, {
                    duration: 600,
                    easing: 'swing', 
                    queue: 'ribbon'
                 }).dequeue('ribbon');

            j(".rib-left").stop('rib-left', true, true).delay(300, 'rib-left').animate({
                "border-right-width": rbw,
                "border-left-width": rbw,
                "border-top-width": rbh,
                "border-bottom-width": rbh,
                "bottom": "-" + (2*rbh) + "px"}, {
                    duration:600,
                    easing: 'linear', 
                    queue: 'rib-left'
                 }).dequeue('rib-left');

            j(".rib-right").stop('rib-right', true, true).delay(300, 'rib-right').animate({
                "border-right-width": rbw,
                "border-left-width": rbw,
                "border-top-width": rbh,
                "border-bottom-width": rbh,
                "bottom": "-" + (2*rbh) + "px"}, {
                    duration:600,
                    easing: 'linear', 
                    queue: 'rib-right'
                 }).dequeue('rib-right');
        });
}
```

You can find my website at: www.egegorgulu.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

```
function rbHover(){
    var timeoutID = 0;
    var hoverInterval = 300;

    j("#nav li a")
        .on('mouseenter', function() {
            clearTimeout(timeoutID);
            timeoutID = setTimeout(mouseEnter, hoverInterval, this);
        })
        .on('mouseleave', function() {
            clearTimeout(timeoutID);
            timeoutID = setTimeout(mouseLeave, hoverInterval);
        });

    function mouseEnter(el) {
        var l = j(el).parent().position().left;
        var w = j(el).parent().width();
        var rbw = Math.round(w/4);
        var rbh = Math.round(w/16);

        j("#ribbon").animate({
            "left" : l,
            "width" : w }, {
            duration: 600,
            easing: 'swing', 
            queue: 'ribbon'
        }).dequeue('ribbon');

        j(".rib-left").stop().animate({
            "border-right-width": rbw,
            "border-left-width": rbw,
            "border-top-width": rbh,
            "border-bottom-width": rbh,
            "bottom": "-" + (2*rbh) + "px"}, {
                duration:600,
                easing: 'linear', 
                queue: 'rib-left'
            }).dequeue('rib-left');

        j(".rib-right").stop().animate({
            "border-right-width": rbw,
            "border-left-width": rbw,
            "border-top-width": rbh,
            "border-bottom-width": rbh,
            "bottom": "-" + (2*rbh) + "px"}, {
                duration:600,
                easing: 'linear', 
                queue: 'rib-right'
            }).dequeue('rib-right');
    }

    function mouseLeave() {
        var l = j(".active").parent().position().left;
        var w = j(".active").parent().width();
        var rbw = Math.round(w/4);
        var rbh = Math.round(w/16);

        j("#ribbon").stop('ribbon', true).animate({
            "left" : l,
            "width" : w }, {
            duration: 600,
            easing: 'swing', 
            queue: 'ribbon'
        }).dequeue('ribbon');

        j(".rib-left").stop('rib-left', true, true).animate({
            "border-right-width": rbw,
            "border-left-width": rbw,
            "border-top-width": rbh,
            "border-bottom-width": rbh,
            "bottom": "-" + (2*rbh) + "px"}, {
                duration:600,
                easing: 'linear', 
                queue: 'rib-left'
            }).dequeue('rib-left');

        j(".rib-right").stop('rib-right', true, true).animate({
            "border-right-width": rbw,
            "border-left-width": rbw,
            "border-top-width": rbh,
            "border-bottom-width": rbh,
            "bottom": "-" + (2*rbh) + "px"}, {
                duration:600,
                easing: 'linear', 
                queue: 'rib-right'
            }).dequeue('rib-right');
    }
}
```

I've just added an interval to the mouseenter event so it waits before firing - change hoverInterval to suit.

Comment: I'm gonna try this now, just wondered why you needed to define the hoverInterval as a variable. Can't I just write 300 in the setTimeout?

Comment: Yes, that's not a problem.  I tend to use variables for things like that as I may change them later or even use them in more than one place.  It's sort of my way of "future proofing" code.

Comment: I've spotted a flaw with my code - it's still relying on `this` even though it's not in scope in the functions.  I'll fix and report.

Comment: Thanks! I just spotted it as well. A little bit explanation on timeoutID would be great too if that's not too much of a trouble for you. I just couldn't wrap my head around it.

Comment: I've just modified it so try the new version.  What it does is create a timeout when the mouseenter event occurs, which is basically a timer with a function attached to it.  When the timeout is reached then the function is fired.  We use timeoutID as a handle to the timer so that we can delete it if the mouse leaves the element before the timer event occurs.  So, it will only trigger mouseEnter when the mouse has been over the element for the given interval.  Bit difficult to put into words - I hope that helps :)

Comment: thanks a lot but now it resets the animation. Can you check my site to see what I mean ( www.egegorgulu.com )

Comment: It was already doing that if you moved the mouse out and then back in again - that's not changed.  I'll see if I can see why, but it's really a 3rd question ;)

Comment: Okay - try the code now.  The "stops" were causing the ribbon to go back to its original position.  I've got rid of them, and the delays, and used a timeout in both enter and leave events.  It runs a lot smoother now.

Comment: AWESOME! Thanks a lot maan. I already accepted it but it would be great if you could just simply explain what does "this" do in the first timeoutID?

Comment: No worries mate.  "this" gets passed into mouseEnter as el, so it can be used in that function.

Comment: hey man, I've been fiddling around a bit in order to apply this technique to all my animations and seems like all these queues and stops are unnecessary altogether. I removed them and the code just keeps working flawlessly. I think the only time I would need such a thing is if the amount of time between the animations and the hoverInterval is too big. Just wanted your opinion on these in case I'm missing something.

Comment: For what you're doing you can remove the stops completely.  If you want to see why they're important though, change the animation interval to something longer like 5 seconds and try to jump around the menu a bit.